# Why is calling DLL with variadic arguments retrieved wrong result and problem solves with extra unused parameter

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, dll, variadic-functions

Platform: x64; Config: Debug; Not reproducible under x86.

Compiler: msvc for both EXE and DLL.

Hi, I have recently encountered a problem while I was developing a DLL. While my sample program is trying to call a DLL export function with variadic argument, I found that when I was trying to call it as the way I wanted, it retrieved the value differs from what I passed into. In a random attempt, I added an `unused` argument and surprisingly found that it retrieved correct value after doing that.

Though I have thought that my goal could be achieved by just making `shapeType`, the last named parameter, to be the first argument of variadic part, but I still wonder why this happens.

I have simplified the code as below (includes are omitted) and recorded something I have found in the address view in the image. The red line in the image represents the address `args`(`va_list`, actually `char*` as defined by the macros while compiling) points to. I have moved up a few lines so that other arguments could be seen as well. Since reproducing problem in this code does not require a meaningful `HWND` value, I just put a random number there. Please contact me if you need whole package of source file including the project file.

It would be such a great thing if you could help me, thanks in advance.

#### exe.cpp

```cpp
#define UNUSED 1
#if UNUSED
typedef int(__cdecl* ADDLINE)(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, int unused, int fillType, float boldness, float a, float r, float g, float b, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
#else
typedef int(__cdecl* ADDLINE)(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, int fillType, float boldness, float a, float r, float g, float b, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
#endif 
int main() {
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"dll.dll");
    ADDLINE addLine = (ADDLINE)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "addShape");
#if UNUSED
    addLine((HWND)0x00000000000b11bc, 16, 2, 1, 10.0f, 127.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
#else
    addLine((HWND)0x00000000000b11bc, 16, 1, 10.0f, 127.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

#### dll.cpp

```cpp
#define UNUSED 1
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int addShape(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, shapeType);
#if UNUSED
    va_arg(args, int); //unused
#endif
    va_arg(args, int); //first int
    std::cout<< va_arg(args, float); //first float
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Memory View Comparison]

#### Text Version

```
0x00000062C7B6F7C0 bc 11 0b 00 00 00 00 00
0x00000062C7B6F7C8 10 00 00 00 ff 7f 00 00
0x00000062C7B6F7D0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00000062C7B6F7D8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x00000062C7B6F7E0 00 00 fe 42 cc cc cc cc
0x00000062C7B6F7E8 00 00 7f 43 cc cc cc cc
UNUSED=0 (without unused), output=0


0x000000FFC20FF600 bc 11 0b 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000FFC20FF608 10 00 00 00 ff 7f 00 00
0x000000FFC20FF610 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000FFC20FF618 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0x000000FFC20FF620 00 00 20 41 cc cc cc cc
0x000000FFC20FF628 00 00 fe 42 cc cc cc cc
UNUSED=1 (with unused), output=10

IEEE-754 Floating Point: 0x41200000==10.0
```

#### Update 2

dll.cpp

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int addShape(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, shapeType);
    va_arg(args, int); //first int
    std::cout<< va_arg(args, float); //first float
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}
```

exe.cpp

```cpp
extern "C" typedef int(__cdecl* ADDLINE)(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, ...);
int main() {
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"dll.dll");
    ADDLINE addLine = (ADDLINE)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "addShape");
    addLine((HWND)0x00000000000b11bc, 16, 1, 10.0f, 127.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Update 1

I have tried some suggestions in the comments but I am not sure whether I was doing correctly. After changing the file `exe.cpp` to the one below, it still does not work except UNUSED=1.
Note: the UNUSED in `dll.cpp` will be set to `1` if it is `1` in `exe.cpp`, otherwise it will be set to `0`.

```cpp
#define UNUSED 0
extern "C"{
#if UNUSED==1
typedef int(__cdecl* ADDLINE)(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, int unused, int fillType, float boldness, float a, float r, float g, float b, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
#elif UNUSED==2
typedef int(__cdecl* ADDLINE)(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, ...);
#else
typedef int(__cdecl* ADDLINE)(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, int fillType, float boldness, float a, float r, float g, float b, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
#endif 
}
int main() {
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"dll.dll");
    ADDLINE addLine = (ADDLINE)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "addShape");
#if UNUSED==1
    addLine((HWND)0x00000000000b11bc, 16, 2, 1, 10.0f, 127.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
#else
    addLine((HWND)0x00000000000b11bc, 16, 1, 10.0f, 127.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or are your two code snippets identical? Can you extract and provide a [mcve] to illustrate the whole? Also, that memory view comparison, can you extract the text? Links to external sites are bad for a Q/A collection and pictures of text are generally frowned upon.

Comment: I am sorry about that the second code was not copied successfully and it read the first code from the clipboard. I have updated it. For the link, since I have not earned enough reputation to have the privilege to show it as an image, I could only put it as an link and could you please help me turn that into an image? Thanks a lot for your help! @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Added text version of the image.

Comment: The behaviour of your code is undefined. ADDLINE **must** be declared with **exactly** the same arguments `addShape` is declared, namely `typedef int(__cdecl* ADDLINE)(HWND hWnd, int shapeType, ...)`. To be pedantically correct, wrap the typedef declaration in `extern "C"`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thanks for your answer! However when I gave it a try it still did not retrieve correct value. I have updated my code in the description and could you please take a look and point out the problem? Thanks again.

Comment: Start with declaring `ADDLINE` correctly and ditching incorrect cases. They are not needed, they can never be used correctly, they do nothing but muddy the waters. Remove all `if UNUSED` statements,  they are not helping.

Comment: `va_arg(args, float);` -- this is illegal. `float` cannot be a variadic parameter. It is always promoted to `double`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and I have done the changes as guided. With the code in `Update 2` it still did not retrieve the correct result.

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh! I have known the problem and thanks a lot!!

Comment: Concerning the hint of @RaymondChen: Have a look at [Variadic arguments - Default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions)

Comment: The problem is solved and thanks a lot for the helps! The knowledge was strengthened.